# How can you define std::variant at compile time if the dependent types are also defined at compile time?

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-macros, c++-templates

Is it possible to use a macro or something similar to create instances of a template class and generate the code that then adds the created variables to a `std::vector` that uses `std::variant`?

Consider this example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

template <typename... Ts>
class Foo
{
};

int main()
{

    // These definitions of Foo shall be produced by the macro
    auto foo1 = std::make_shared<Foo<int, int, int>>(Foo<int, int, int>());
    auto foo2 = std::make_shared<Foo<int, int>>(Foo<int, int>());

    // The variants shall be done with respect to the instantiations of Foo
    std::vector<std::variant<decltype(foo1), decltype(foo2)>> objects;

    return 0;
}
```

foo1 and foo2 two create two types of the class Foo since they are using different template parameters. Therefore, the `std::vector<std::variant<...>>` objects is able to hold two variants. If one would define a foo3 with a different type than the two before, it should come with three variants accordingly. Is this possible?

Or a macros in general not capable of handling data types as input?

Comment: Don't use macros(when it can be done without it).

Comment: Macros do text substitution on source code.   Although the preprocessor can recognise some C++ syntactic elements, it knows nothing about data types.

Comment: *"How can I use a macro..."* Why not just create a constexpr function template here instead of a macro? Also we need an [mcve]. What is `Foo`?

Comment: https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for. Yet is what you're describing really the design you're looking for?

Comment: @Artyer Yes, you are right. That was a typo, sorry! I tried to make the example code more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, variables of the form `foo1`, `foo2`, ..., `fooN` should be in a container instead. An array won't work because the types are different, but a tuple will.

A helper function can help you call `make_shared` for each type:

```cpp
template<typename... InputTypes, typename Factory>
constexpr auto map_types(Factory&& f) {
    return std::make_tuple(f(std::type_identity<InputTypes>{})...);
}

auto foos = map_types<
    Foo<int, int, int>,
    Foo<int, int>
>([]<class T>(std::type_identity<T>) {
    return std::make_shared<T>();
});

// foo1 -> std::get<0>(foos)
// foo2 -> std::get<1>(foos)

// Or for convenience
auto& [ foo1, foo2 ] = foos;
```

And the type of `foos` will be `std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Foo<int, int, int>>, std::shared_ptr<Foo<int, int>>>`, which you can programmatically transform into your variant type:

```cpp
using variant_type = decltype([]<typename... T>(std::tuple<T...> const&) -> std::variant<T...> { std::unreachable(); }(foos));
std::vector<variant_type> objects;
```

If you wanted to add or remove any types, you only have to change the template parameters given to `map_types<...>`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use macro with modern c++ as you can write a `constexpr` *variadic function template*  as shown below:

```
template<typename... T>
constexpr auto make_foo()
{
    return std::make_shared<Foo<T...>>();
}

auto foo1 = make_foo<int, int, int>();
auto foo2 = make_foo<int, int>();
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x4M3ezTGv)

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. This tackles the first half of my question, but what about the type deduction for the definition of "objects"?